# How to generate a list of numbers, skipping numbers contained in another list?

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Let me try to explain...

Suppose I have the list 2, 5, 8.

I want to generate a new list that skips these numbers. Now suppose the starting point of my new list is the consecutive range 1 to 8. Unfortunately, this 2nd list duplicates 3 of the numbers from the first list, so numbers in the 2nd list need to be adjusted by the appropriate amount to remove these duplications.

1st list: 2  5  8

2nd list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

adj list: 1 3 4 6 7 9 10 11

To arrive at the adjusted list I have effectively added in an offset, based on the first list:

offset  : 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 3

To skip over the 2 in the 2nd list (because it is present in the first list), I have to add in the position 2 offset; i.e. 2 + 1 = 3.

It's important to understand that prior adjustments also affect values in the 2nd list, even if that value doesn't appear in the first list; e.g. 6 appears in the 2nd list but not the 1st, but it still needs to be adjusted to preserve the relationship between the 2nd list and the resulting adj list. So the 6 in the 2nd list is adjusted by the position 6 offset: i.e. 6 + 3 = 9.

Things get more complicated when there is/are consecutive number range(s) in the 1st list:

1st list: 2 5 6 9

2nd list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

adj list: 1 3 4 7 8 10 11 12

offset  : 0 1 1 3 3 4 4 4

What I am looking for is an Excel array formula to calculate the offsets. But... there are a number of conditions:

1. The 1st list will have up to 5 unsorted numbers.
2. The 2nd list will have up to 54 unsorted numbers.
3. All numbers are positive integers.
4. Avoid helper cells.
5. Definitely no VBA.

I am open to other ways to achieve the end result, but my preference is to use a self-contained array formula.

I will be very interested to see what you peeps can come up with, excluding VBA.

Many thanks,

Comment: Any chance of adding maybe 3 or 4 more varied examples with expected results (no explanations necessary, though)?

Comment: Also, do you want only the offsets, or will you accept a solution which generates the final list, though perhaps via a different method than that which generates the offsets?

Comment: Here's an example with an all consecutive 1st list:

1st list: 4 5 6
2nd list: 1 2 3 4 5 6
adj list: 1 2 3 7 8 9
offset  : 0 0 0 3 3 3

Comment: Thanks. Have you thought about my other question?

Comment: Another 1st list example with 2 consecutive ranges and very compressed spread (i.e. 1 to 7), requiring numbers on the 2nd list to have more accelerated offsets:

1st list: 1 2 4 5 7
2nd list: 1 2 3 4 5 6
adj list: 3 6 8 9 10 11
offset  : 2 4 5 5 5 5

Comment: I'm open to ideas XOR LX: a solution that just gives the offsets, or gives the final list is fine. But, allowing for the conditions above. The unsorted condition is very important to me.

Comment: With the 1st list in A1:A5 and the 2nd list in column B, the following formula (in the next comment) in column C would correctly calculate the offset. But, it's horrible, and needs one COUNTIF per number in the 1st list...

Comment: =COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<="&B1+COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<="&1+COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<="&B1+COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<="&B1+COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<="&B1)))))

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is the "unsorted" thing.  Here is a method to exclude one list from another.  Put the list of items to be excluded in column **A** and put the large candidate list in column **B**.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A$1:A$8,0)),B1,"")
```

and copy down.  Here is an example:

[image]

We can produce a list without blank cells, or even sorted, but this might require helper columns.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I had considered this approach, but there seems to be no way to correctly pick the number that's been shifted on by the content of the 1st list.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there's a more succinct solution, but, with *List1* and *List2* defined appropriately, and assuming you have Excel 2010 or later (small change required if not):

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNT(List2),"",IF(ROWS($1:1)>SUMPRODUCT(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(List2,List1,0))),MAX(List1)+ROWS($1:1)-SUMPRODUCT(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(List2,List1,0))),AGGREGATE(15,6,List2/(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(List2,List1,0))),ROWS($1:1))))`

Copy down until you start to get blanks.

Regards

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be given the expected result. I've got a 1st list of: 14 25 5 2 39. The first number of the 2nd list is 11. The output from your routine is 11, but it should be 13. Do you get 11 or 13? NB - I'm amazed you came up with this in just a few minutes!

Comment: I'm only currently using the numbers 1 to 59 in both list1 and list2 and, with that restriction, your formula is giving the same result as my: =AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(--((--ISERROR(MATCH(ROW($1:$59),List1,0)))*ROW($1:$59)>=List2))*ROW($1:$59),1)

Comment: So I now know that your formula will definitely output 11 rather than the 13 that it should...

Comment: Not sure I understand. In all 4 of the examples which you provided the lists were in ascending numerical order. Are you saying that those examples were in fact not representative of your actual data? Try changing INDEX(List1,COUNT(List1)) to MAX(List1).

Comment: Sorry, I used ascending order to better illustrate what was happening, but both lists will, in reality, be unsorted. I will try your suggested change, cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same result. This is because your formula is doing a lookup against List2, as was mine, to find the first available value greater than or equal to the particular value in List2. But what is really needed is a formula to calculate the offsets for all values from 1 to MAX(List2), and then use the values in List2 as an index into the list of offsets. The List2 value and offset value (for the List2 value) can then be added together to produce the final list of adjusted values.

Comment: Ah, wait. I think I overcomplicated things. Have amended.

Comment: P.S. When stating whether a given solution works or not, would you be able to post a single counter-example to that effect?

Comment: Sure...! List1: 5 2 9 6. List2: 5 4 12 13 6 10 9 16 2. Offsets (for List2 values 1 to 16): 0 1 1 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4. To calculate the adjusted List2 values we take each value of List2 and add the appropriate offset; i.e. 1st List2 value is 5 + 3 (the 5th offset value) = 8. This process would produce an adjusted List2 list of: 8 7 16 17 10 14 13 20 3. Using your formula, the adjusted List2 would be calculated as: 7 4 12 13 7 10 11 16 3.

Comment: Various anomalies stem from your calculation method: 4 12 13 10 and 16 are unchanged between List2 and the Adjusted list. This is wrong because earlier values in List1 must displace all later List2 values. Also, List1 contains the sequence "10 9", but this becomes mapped to "10 11" in the Adjusted list; i.e. the relative magnitudes are reversed.

Comment: In that case, apologies, but I do not know how to solve your problem.

Comment: No probs XOR LX - thanks for spending time to look at this!